# Row group not repeating even though RepeatonNewPage is on

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I've got this table within a report which is built as follows:

```
HEADER ROW (10 columns)
----
BUYER NAME 1 column
----
BUYER REGION 1column
----
results (10 columns)
```

The layout is not to be switched around. There are multiple buyer regions possible per buyer. However, the header row for results is not duplicating on every page even though KeepWithGroup is set to After and RepeatOnNewPage is set to true.
How do I set it so the header row is repeated?
The Row Groups look as follows (Screenshot).
The top (Static) should be on every page. 
[image]

Comment: what if you got to tablix property and remove all the ticks (if any) in the Row Headers and Column Headers section under General?

Comment: I've fixed it. Totally remade the table as I couldn't find where the issue was.